# Find lowest values from multiple Columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, function

How could I select the lowest 3 numbers from multiple columns?

```
id          num1        num2        num3        num4        num5
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           6           5           1           2
2           6           2           2           3           2
3           2           1           2           1           5
4           4           1           1           5           7
5           5           1           4           7           8
```

For example

(lowest 2 values from id 1) > ((lowest 2 values from id 5)

Comment: The only remotely nice way I see would be to unpivot each row.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: Do you just need to know what the numbers are, or do you also need to know which `id` row and/or `num` column they came from. Also, how should your query deal with duplicates? From your data set as shown, would you want the three lowest numbers to show as 1, 1 and 1, or would you want to see 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: For example, lowest 2 values in id 1 would give 1,1

Answer (score 3):

One method uses `cross apply`:

```
select t.id, v.num
from t cross apply
     (select top 3 num
      from (values (num1), (num2), (num3), (num4), (num5)) v(num)
      order by num asc
     ) v;
```

If you want them in the same row, then re-pivot:

```
select t.id, v.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then num end) as num1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then num end) as num2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then num end) as num3                 
      from (select num, row_number() over (order by num) as seqnum
            from (values (num1), (num2), (num3), (num4), (num5)) v(num)
           ) v
      ) v;
```

Comment: @SqlZim . . . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `order by desc` and select `top` of the rows like

```
select top 3 num1, num2, num3
from tbl1
order by num1 desc, num2 desc, num3 desc
```